# Ratings not reflected for certain list items in SharePoint 2010 site

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, rating

User has created a list and enabled rating in the list in his SharePoint2010 publishing site.
User tried to rate the list items, the rating did not reflect even after few days.

We tried creating test items similar to the user created items in the same list and with the same user permission, we rated the items. It reflected after the below jobs ran.

User Profile Service – Social Data Maintenance Job
User Profile Service Proxy – Social Rating Synchronization Job

Only for the user created items, the rating are not getting set even after the above jobs run as per schedule. But if we run the jobs immediately, its working in those items as well. Seems bizarre.

Kindly help on this.

Answer (score 0):

Found the Answer. The ampersand in the title column has caused the issue. If the title is without the ampersand column, it works fine.